# In Rails, display in View.rb scraped link variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I've made the following Controller, which parses file link to make the file downloadable in my application.

Since I can't find a way to create my View.rb, what is the best way to dispay my varaiables (scraped links) in my View.rb ? already tried <%= variable %>, in vain.

**Home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    begin
    openlink = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com/"))
    variable = {}
    openlink.xpath('some regex').each do |link|
      variable[link.text.strip] = link['href']
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The `begin` statement in your method is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller make `variable` an instance variable by adding the `@` to it.

like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    openlink = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com/"))
    @variable = {}
    openlink.xpath('some regex').each do |link|
      @variable[link.text.strip] = link['href']
    end
  end
end
```

then in your `app/views/home/index.html.erb` put:

```
<% @variable.each do |k, v| %>
 <%= "#{k}: #{v}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: edited my answer, `variable` was only a local variable in the controller, by making it an instance variable the view now has access to it.

Comment: Yes I did, I used first an instance variable (@variable), unfortunatly, it doesn't work

Comment: is your code available for me to see?  If not, make sure `@variable` contains something.  in your view put `<% if @variable.empty? %>  wow this thing is empty! <% end %>`

Comment: I was pretty sure that my instance variable were not nil, however your code did confirmed me this fact. I tried to start your first suggestion by '<% if @variable %> ', but oddly, it works only when i refresh the page, not first time ! (deleted cache and restarted server, same thing, works only if I refresh the page)